# Original 'this' context with Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io, prototype

I have wrapped (client-side) socket.io in a prototype class:

```
Chat.Client = Class.create();

Chat.Client.prototype = {

    initialize: function() {
        ...
        this.socket.on('message', this.on_message);
        ...
    },

    on_message: function(data) {
        this.add_chat_message(data.something);
    }

    do_something: function(something) {
        ...
    }
```

This does not work because 'this' in on_message will be 'SocketNamespace'. Traditionally I would work around this by just passing 'this' into the callback as an additional parameter, but because I am using socket.io, I cannot simply do this.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap it in another function:

```
initialize: function() {
  // ...
  var client = this;
  this.socket.on('message', function(data) { client.on_message(data); });
```

In newer browsers (or Node.js) you can alternatively use a function on the `Function` prototype called "bind":

```
  this.socket.on('message', this.on_message.bind(this));
```

The "bind" function returns a function that, when called, will force the original function ("on_message") to be invoked with the given value as the `this` value.

Comment: Thank you, bind will work. (now I'll just have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer)

Comment: Small addition: known JS libs provide binding functionality. If one uses [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.com), there's crossbrowser `bind` function in it: `_.bind(function(){ ... }, this)`. Also there's `proxy` function in jQuery, which does the same thing: `$.proxy(function(){ ... }, this)`. Here is a [performance test with examples](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/5) for all means to do this.

Comment: @HighCat yes, thanks for that addendum. The jQuery `$.proxy()` is not quite as good as `.bind()`, but it serves for most normal purposes. There's also the [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) JavaScript library, which provides an even richer set of binding and "currying" utilities.